# How to migrate alfresco community database from 3.2 to 5?

Tags: server, alfresco

Well, i'm thinking about to upgrade my alfresco installation. I have the 3.2 version and i'm gonna install the 5.0 on another server, but i wanna migrate the database and i don't know if i have to do extra steps to make it work.
So my question is: 
do the two versions have the same db schema? it's just put the data and link the new installation?

Comment: As per [the Official Docs on Upgrade paths](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/upgrade-path.html) you'll need to go via 4.x to go from 3.2 to 5.0

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. Move the 3.2 installation to the new server by dumping/loading the database and copying/relocating the content store. This will be your new live server when you've got everything worked out.
2. Upgrade from 3.2 to 3.3.
3. Upgrade from 3.3 to 3.4.
4. Upgrade from 3.4 to 4.2. At this point you can begin running SOLR.
5. Upgrade from 4.2 to 5.0.
6. Upgrade from 5.0 to 5.2.

Between each of those upgrade steps you'll need to let the server come up to migrate your DB schema. If you have problems, you'll need to address those before continuing.

Once it looks good, take a backup. That way, if you have to revert, you won't have to repeat a step.

Depending on the customizations you've made, you might be able to ignore whether or not they work until the final upgrade, because you aren't going to be on any intermediate version for long.

Another thing you must consider while you're doing this is whether or not you are running on "supported" OS, database, Java, and app server for each of the hops. You are starting with a very old version so this may be difficult to achieve.

Once you've made it to the final version you would like to go-live with, and you've identified all of the steps you need to take along the way to get the db schema updated, and assuming you have been using your old server this whole time, it's time to cut over with the latest data.

To cut over, you'll dump the db again and do an rsync of the existing content to your new server. Now you are ready to repeat your upgrade steps which should work since you've tested them already.

Once that final version comes up and your customizations are all set, you can swing the DNS and turn off your old server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow a proper upgrade path, meaning you will first upgrade to 4.x, and only then to 5.0 (like @Gagravarr already said).

Don't forget to take into account the fact that 5.0 uses SOLR as a default indexing engine, and that you will need to rebuild your indexes to accommodate this.

Don't forget that SOLR is eventually consistent too, and if transactional consistency is important to you, you may need to switch some queries to FTS/CMIS.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Gagravarr and @Jeff Potts that you need to follow the proper upgrade path as mentioned in the Alfresco documentation.
A complete set of instructions is provided here [Alfresco Upgrade](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ch-upgrade.html)

Also, a few points to note with respect to version 5:

1. As @Lista mentioned that version 5.0 uses SOLR as a default indexing engine and you will need to reindex all your data,convert your queries to FTS and use transactional metadata queries in your application **if required**.
2. `Alfresco Explorer` is no more. So if you have any customization done for your existing clients in explorer, you will have to use the new `Share` UI or build a new UI yourself using familiar technologies.
3. Before you run your upgrade, make sure that you have validated your entire architecture which is mentioned here [zeroday-architecture](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/zeroday-architecture.html)

Comment: Mentioning Alfresco Explorer is a nice touch!